# Angular Universal with dynamic page cache using CDN

Tags: angular, angular-universal

questions is regarding angular universal with dynamic page cache using CDN

1) in my application if rendered html served from CDN cache then why async API calls made after page loaded while all rendered data served from CDN, so could you please help us how we can stop these unnecessary api's calls when page source getting from CDN

Comment: Use TransferState API to cache the data server side during rendering and use it client side, without extra request, once the page is loaded

Comment: Is TransferState cache working with Angular 4?